# Breakpoint-counter: Only stop at Matlab breakpoint the second (nth) time it is hit

Tags: matlab, breakpoints

I am looking for a way to set up a conditional breakpoint that only stops the second (or n-th) time the condition is met, for example:

```
function f = myfunc(x)
for t = 1:1000
   x = x+x^0.5; %I want to stop here the second time the function is called and t == 666
end
f = x;
```

I know how to stop at the breakpoint each time the condition is met, but if I want to look at the second time it is hit I first need to wait for a few minutes, then hit f5 and wait for another few minutes. This is quite annoying as it makes me lose focus once more then required. If I want to look at the 10th time, it is even worse.

I am looking for a solution that does not require me to adjust the code of the function in which I need to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fun idea, that I think gives you a partial solution.

Write a function `mystop.m`:

```
function flag = mystop

persistent counter

if isempty(counter)
    counter = 0;
else
    counter = counter+1;
end

if counter>=2
    flag = true;
else
    flag = false;
end
```

Now set a conditional breakpoint within `myfunc` at the line `x = x+x^0.5;`, with the condition being

```
t == 666 && feval(@()mystop)
```

Set up a test function to exercise `myfunc` a few times:

```
function [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5] = mytest

clear mystop

f1= myfunc(1)
f2= myfunc(2)
f3= myfunc(3)
f4= myfunc(4)
f5= myfunc(5)
```

When you run `mytest`, it should stop only the *second* time the line in `myfunc` is hit (and t is 666) - in other words, while `f2` is being calculated.

Note that you need to include the line `clear mystop`, in order to reset the persistent variable between calls to `mytest`. Alternatively, you could just manually call `clear mystop` between runs of `mytest`.

Obviously - if you want it stop only after the 3rd, 10th, nth time etc, modify the condition `counter>=2` above to `counter>=n`.

Comment: Looks very promising! Still need to test it, but then I guess this is easily generalized by giving mystop the counter limit as input.

Comment: Yes, I think you should be able to generalize it and make it more robust in quite a few ways - the above is just a quick example that seemed to get close to a solution. PS I think you should be able to replace `feval(@()mystop)` with just `mystop` - not quite sure why I overcomplicated it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll HAVE to adjust code, manage a flag there which can count the number of times it have reached there